# Too restrictive with permitted number of links for a new user

Tags: support

I have a question about my Super User post: [Linux subsytem for windows not launching](https://superuser.com/questions/1109734/linux-subsytem-for-windows-not-launching)

I have more research information to provide to help with the question. But I'm restricted to only 2 links per post since I'm a new user with no reputation! Isn't this too restrictive for a user and won't such restrictions even kill the purpose of having such a forum? My purpose here is not to build reputation but to get my true and genuine questions answered!

Comment: Waiting now for users to go blindly upvoting the question out of pity instead helping you out by editing in those links

Comment: Related: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129833/warn-new-users-earlier-that-they-cannot-post-links-or-images) and [our help](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/new-user) tells you *why* we have these restrictions.

Comment: You should leave comments indicating what urls you want added.  I won't be upvoting your question for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Its a spam reduction method - it makes it harder for someone to create a account, post a dozen spam links and run away.

That said you've passed the (very minimal) amount of reputation (10) to remove new user restrictions (congratulations!). You can now update your post with the necessary links. The question itself seems fine, all it needed was time and eyeballs.

Comment: That's precisely my point. For someone who is new to the site, trying to get an answer quickly to solve their problem, having to wait and earn reputation itself is a big let down. 

Yes, spam control should be done. But there are much better moderation mechanisms for it. So for someone who wants to spam, isn't it an easy choice to earn 10 reputations and then spam as much as they want until  one of the better moderation mechanisms catch him? And if we have a mechanism later to catch him, why wouldn't it help to stop it in the beginning itself?

Comment: I'm trying to make a bigger point here. **If someone wants to spam, first two links are enough to do it!** Restricting the number of links to a bare min of 2 for a new user is too draconian IMHO.

Comment: @VivekVijayan - If you are using several links, you should be quoting the material already, you don't have to make the links clickable.